# How do I make a good SQL search?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, search

I have a search field, and using that single text box I want the user to be able to find both galleries and images by their name. The problem I'm having is that I don't seem to be able to get any results on my queries, even though the syntax is fine and I get no errors.

Here's the scenario: My group name is "Liten gruppe!", and the search string is "liten". Both the search string and result string is switched to lower case for non-case sensitive search.

Something in the syntax must be doing something I'm not expecting.

```
SELECT `id`
FROM gallery_groups
WHERE   `name` LIKE LOWER('%$searchstring%') OR
        `date_created` LIKE LOWER('%$searchstring%');
```

Thanks for any help

---

EDIT: OK, that was a stupid mistake. But the correction still yields no results:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM gallery_groups
WHERE   LOWER(`name`) LIKE '%$searchstring%' OR
        LOWER(`date_created`) LIKE '%$searchstring%';
```

---

EDIT: Interesting! Copying the resulting query directly into PhpMyAdmin results in a match. It does NOT result in any rows when called from PHP however. How can that be?

---

EDIT: OK, it turns out that the query does indeed return 1 result. I was fooled by the dump output of the result:

```
object(mysqli_result)[3]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
```

If all the fields in the result are null, how can I possibly know if there are any results other than running fetch_object() ?

Comment: are you sure your search string is getting inserted into the query?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the query your code generates, and running it directly against the database outside of PHP? That usually turns up the easy-to-spot mistakes.

Comment: @Sarah Happy: Yes, I have done that. @Dan Grossman: I have not done that. Let me try it out

Comment: Interesting! Copying the resulting query directly into PhpMyAdmin results in a match. It does NOT result in any rows when called from PHP however. How can that be?

Comment: It means your code is wrong. You thought you didn't need to provide your code to get an answer, but you do ;)

Comment: Updated - And i have to write more in this comment in order to submit it (stupid anti spam system)

Comment: "how can I possibly know if there are any results" By using `mysql_num_rows($result)` or your abstraction layer's equivalent. This isn't a discussion forum, please post a complete question that can be answered.

Comment: Well it turns out that the problem I thought I had wasn't my problem. Changing the question would be frowned upon seing as I already have answers. Thus I'll close the question. Thanks for the help Dan. EDIT: OK turns out I can't delete a question with answers. I voted to close it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `msql_query` to get your result object, in which case you can use `mysql_num_rows` to get the number of rows in the result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

You can issue case insensitive searches in MYSQL without `LOWER`:

```
WHERE   `name` COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$searchstring%' OR
        `date_created` COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$searchstring%';
```

AS for debugging: Try to print the SQL queries as they are passed to the database to see, if you really use the intended search string.

Comment: Then how would I perform case-sensitive searches? Also, won't changing the character encoding to UTF8 corrupt my characters? (I.E. Æ, Ø, Å)

Comment: Do not confuse character set (encoding) and collation. Collation just defines ordering (what characters come before others and which are considered equal). To perform a case-sensitive search, use a case-sensitive collation.

Comment: I should add, you don't have to use UTF8. MySQL supports 70+ collations for 30+ character sets. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-charsets.html

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps you to find out if your query returns any rows. 
but this is how i do it:

$strSQL = "SELECT `id` ";
$strSQL .= "FROM gallery_groups ";
$strSQL .= "WHERE   LOWER(`name`) LIKE '%$searchstring%' OR ";
$strSQL .= "       LOWER(`date_created`) LIKE '%$searchstring%'";

$rec = mysql_query($strSQL,$oConn);

if (mysql_num_rows($rec)>0) {
    $strName = mysql_result($rec,0,"name");
    $strDateCreated = mysql_result($rec,0,"date_created");
}